# Lvextend don't find free space

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, lvm

I'm trying to expand my lvm partition on Ubuntu 16.04, but

```
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/Server0-vg/root
```

shows

```
New size (3861 extents) matches existing size (3861 extents)
Run `lvextend --help' for more information.
```

My lvm partition is /dev/sda5 and it is in /dev/sda2 - both are 159GB.
lvdisplay shows:

```
--- Logical volume ---
LV Path                /dev/Server0-vg/root
LV Name                root
VG Name                Server0-vg
LV UUID                fxh0JM-oKQM-nIrj-c5S0-Tlw6-GGKX-2vcZY8
LV Write Access        read/write
LV Creation host, time Server0, 2004-11-29 01:15:23 +0100
LV Status              available
# open                 1
LV Size                15,08 GiB
Current LE             3861
Segments               2
Allocation             inherit
Read ahead sectors     auto
- currently set to     256
Block device           252:0

--- Logical volume ---
LV Path                /dev/Server0-vg/swap_1
LV Name                swap_1
VG Name                Server0-vg
LV UUID                ZxV31F-BLza-3QaB-awXX-3IBt-SvzA-Lo2RAj
LV Write Access        read/write
LV Creation host, time Server0, 2004-11-29 01:15:24 +0100
LV Status              available
# open                 2
LV Size                508,00 MiB
Current LE             127
Segments               1
Allocation             inherit
Read ahead sectors     auto
- currently set to     256
Block device           252:1
```

(If someone not get, i want to expand /dev/Server0-vg/root to 159gb)

df -h shows:

```
Filesystem                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                          737M     0  737M   0% /dev
tmpfs                         151M  5,1M  146M   4% /run
/dev/mapper/Server0--vg-root   15G  6,7G  7,3G  48% /  
tmpfs                         754M     0  754M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                         5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                         754M     0  754M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                     472M  453M     0 100% /boot
tmpfs                         100K     0  100K   0% /run/lxcfs/controllers
tmpfs                         151M     0  151M   0% /run/user/1000
```

'print' in parted shows:

```
Model: ATA WDC WD1600BB-56R (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 160GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   Type      File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  512MB  511MB  primary   ext2         boot
 2      513MB   160GB  159GB  extended
 5      513MB   160GB  159GB  logical                lvm
```

Result of sudo vgdisplay:

```
--- Volume group ---

VG Name               Server0-vg
System ID             
Format                lvm2
Metadata Areas        1
Metadata Sequence No  4
VG Access             read/write
VG Status             resizable
MAX LV                0
Cur LV                2
Open LV               2
Max PV                0
Cur PV                1
Act PV                1
VG Size               15,58 GiB
PE Size               4,00 MiB
Total PE              3988
Alloc PE / Size       3988 / 15,58 GiB
Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
VG UUID               302ela-v51W-hM2T-zjdv-8QtK-ZFBc-SW1D5Y
```

Result of sudo pvdisplay:

```
--- Physical volume ---
PV Name               /dev/sda5
VG Name               Server0-vg
PV Size               15,58 GiB / not usable 4,00 MiB
Allocatable           yes (but full)
PE Size               4,00 MiB
Total PE              3988
Free PE               0
Allocated PE          3988
PV UUID               6j391r-dL9l-8Rw8-kGt4-Ewxg-NiyM-rjzggr
```

Comment: Please add the output of `sudo pvdisplay`and `sudo vgdisplay`. You first might have to increase the volume group first.

Comment: Added. (15 characters minimum..)

Comment: Physical Volume (PV) is still 15 Gb, you have to pvresize /dev/sda first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your `Physical volume` only is of size 15,58 GiB, the `Volume group`and thus the `Logical Volume`cannot be larger.

First you have to resize the physical volume:

```
sudo pvresize /dev/sda5
```

(see `man pvresize` for options). If you do not want it to resize to the max, use option `--setphysicalvolumesize`.

Now again look at `vgdisplay`to see if the volume group has been extended as well.